# Java create PDF or Image from an invalid HTML

Tags: c#, java, html, validation, pdf

I want to create **PDF** (or any of image formats [**png, jpg, bmp**..]) from an 'invalid' **HTML** file using **Java**. I googled it and find a tool: [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/), and some of tutorials that using iText to create PDF from HTML with Java.

In this tutorial [(X)HTML to PDF with Java](http://goo.gl/kykU3) , it works for a valid HTML correctly and i had a PDF file like [this](http://goo.gl/rHl8H). But if i tried to create PDF from my HTML i had some errors.

First of all my HTML is not well formed and unfortunately does not possible to change. I uploaded it to [here](http://goo.gl/hXJKW) and W3C's validator found [28 errors](http://goo.gl/PQc79).

My options are:

- First clean and valid my HTML and create PDF soon.
- Find another tool (which works for my problem).
- Your suggestion (using Java).
- Last option; use an another platform (**.net, Php, Python** etc.) and
  using Webservices from my application.

Please help me about this issue. Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems like you're 'almost there'. My personal take on that would be to fix the HTML and use the tool which works, as you have seen for yourself. Fixing 28 HTML errors (especially if that's your own template and not something you get from 'outside') will be arguably easier and quicker than transition to other platform or tool, which _also may not work_ with invalid HTML.

Comment: This HTML is one of thousands variations. It is not static and (can) change dynamically in every call.

Comment: The problem is that it's completely normal for two different programs to render **valid** HTML differently, let alone **invalid** HTML. What exactly is the source of the HTML? Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: Even though you say you can't, you really need to fix your HTML

Comment: @RoToRa, as i stated the question, it is not possible to change HTML. HTML file created and gave me another system and i can not interfere the system (SAP PI)

Comment: Considering SAP is a huge company that provides support (I assume) it should be possible to file a bug against the HTML issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `wkhtmltopdf`. This uses the Headless browser (webkit) to render the html first and then generates the PDF. I was using this with in one of my java projects and worked well.

It provides some flexible command line options, [Here](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html) is the link for list of options and its usage. It works for htmls those are not well formed also.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a tool like http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/ to fix the HTML for you and run iText against the jTidy's output...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it now and it is not working for my problem.

Comment: It gave me an XML which looks like better than first html; than used iText and it gave me a PDF. But the PDF file does not look like Firefox's interpret, they are different..

Comment: I see. You could try out other HTML-tidying solutions instead of jTidy, since if the specialized tool hasn't done job good enough for you, I doubt other converters will do it any better...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a HTML parser that supports broken HTML such as [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Like jtidy it can automatically create valid HTML, but it also allows you to manipulate the HTML DOM, so you could try and fix the biggest problems yourself explicitly the way you want it.